# How to add single vertices onto the surface of a mesh?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, vertices, snapping

When `Ctrl + Right Mouse Button` clicking to add a single vertex, how do you make the vertex snap to other existing geometry?

In the depicted example I need to add some edges between the spheres, and to achieve this I'd like to quickly add verts onto the surface of the spheres. The verts does not need to become a part of the sphere mesh, it only needs to land onto that geometry.

[image: Example scene]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just had the same problem and snap with the option "face project" works by adding a vertex by ctrl + right click. The vertex will be projected onto the face underneath the mouse cursor. I'm using Blender 3.3.1.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible to use ctrl+RMB and snap at the same time. However, if you would use E to extrude a vertex and have Snap to Faces enabled at the same time, you can do what you trying to achieve, I think.

[image]